# Iterate through objects in Angular $$nextSibling

Tags: angularjs, loops, traversal

In the Angular element with `e2e-class books-list` I have books under a specific category and subcategory.

I'd like to iterate through all the objects and get the titles of the books stored here but am not familiar with Angular and not sure how to proceed.

So basically what I want is to have the first title under $parent.category.subcat.title and then continue for all of the $$nextSibling.

Script:

```
angular.element('[e2e-class=books-list]').scope().$parent.category.subcat.title; //first book title

angular.element('[e2e-class=books-list]').scope().$parent.$$nextSibling.category.subcat.title; //second sibling book title

angular.element('[e2e-class=books-list]').scope().$parent.$$nextSibling.$$nextSibling.category.subcat.title; //third sibling book title
```

Script (iterating):  *This is how I would usually do*

```
var myElem = angular.element('[e2e-class=books-list]').scope().$parent;
function getNextSiblings(elem) {
    var elemSibs = [];
    while (elem = elem.nextSibling) {
        elemSibs.push(elem.category.subcat.title);
    }
    return elemSibs;
}

getNextSiblings(myElem);
```

Actual Result:

```
[]
```

Expected Result:

```
["Book1", "Book2", "Book3"]
```

Footnote: Angular v.1.4.14

Comment: Sorry, just as I published I noticed my error.

I put elem.nextSibling instead of elem.$$nextSibling.

Comment: You can just delete the question if an answer is not needed any more as it doesn't seem to be a generic problem others might have too :-)